# HTML table data arrangement

Tags: html, html-table

I have a question about HTML table arrangement.

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
```

I get elements arranged like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Is it possible first fill all first column (not the row), then fill second column and so on? I want to get something like this:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: With html its not possible.

Comment: The numbers are hard coded, just copy paste them in the TDs you want... 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9.

Comment: Sure it's possible, but it would probably look confusing from a development standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **HTML** you actually need:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is added dynamic to your table, it is not possible. But you can achieve the same desired effect using `.div`'s. A little bit of CSS is needed to achieve the same effects:

I quickly created a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0dpn1ccu/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply transpose rows to columns by adding css

```css
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

When thinking of adding data inside the table. We reason in terms of rows,
which means we add rows into a table (not columns). We'll define
columns inside a row.

the data should be arranged like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

you can check *https://html.com/tables/* for more details.